# finding fault in an apparent argument for non-additivity of outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am going through the following book on measure theory :

http://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf

At page 36 , the author is starting with the proof for "There exists disjoint subsets $\ A$ and $\ B$ of $\ R$ such that the outer measure of $\ A \Cup B $ is not equal to the sum of the outer measures of these two sets "

On going through the proof it seems the author has made use of Axiom of choice .

However , I am unable to find the problem in the simplistic argument to prove the above , which goes as follow :

"By definition , outer measure of a set $\ X $ is the infimum of sum of the lengths of sets whose union contains $\ X$ .Hence if we consider the set of rational numbers in [ 0 ,1] then  [0,1] is the smallest set which contains all the rational numbers in [0,1] , so it is for the set of irrational numbers in [0,1] . Now it is as well the minimum set containing the union of these two sets . However , as we can clearly see the sum of the outer measures of these sets is twice the sum of the outer measure of their union "

I feel there is something wrong in the argument but I am unable to figure it out .

Comment: The outer measure of the rationals is $0$. For two disjoint sets whose union has outer measure different from the sum of the outer measures of the parts, you need non-measurable sets, and without choice it's consistent that all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I think I need to understand choice more to understand this

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following open cover of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ by a sequence $(q_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. For $q_1$, choose an open ball of diameter $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ around $q_1$. Then, for $q_2$, choose an open ball of diameter $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ around $q_2$. Similarly, for any $n$, choose an open ball of diameter $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ around $q_n$. You have thus covered the rationals in $[0,1]$ by a sequence of intervals with overall measure which is at most $\epsilon$ (using the formula for the sum of a geometric series) - and $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small.

Do you see the problem with your argument now? $[0,1]$ is clearly not the 'smallest' cover of the rationals  via intervals- they are a set of measure $0$, so they can be covered by something arbitrarily small. So you cannot claim that their outer measure is equal to that of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @GSsofer : Are you assuming that q_n+1 does not fall under the open ball centered at q_n ?

Comment: No, I don't need to assume that, since the outer measure is sub-additive. If they intersect, the measure can only get smaller (that's why the outer measure of the given open cover is AT MOST $\epsilon$)

Comment: We can do a similar argument for irrationals  but isn't the union of rationals and irrationals [0,1] which is of measure 1 thereby giving an example for the inequality in question ?

Comment: We cannot do this, since the outer measure is determined by a countable union of intervals, and so this construction will not work for the irrationals (since they are uncountable).

Comment: There I see the point I was missing . Thanks a lot

Comment: On thinking again , does this same collection of balls not cover the irrationals as well ? Let us assume that it has left an irrational number . However, we can find a rational sufficiently close to it , so that the irrational number falls within the range of this rational number . So this way no irrational numbers are left excluded by this union of balls centered at rational numbers .

Comment: It doesn't have to cover every irrational (in fact, for $\epsilon<1$ it necessarily won't). Think about it like this - although any irrational has a rational arbitrarily close to it, the open balls around rationals get exponentially small with n. So although there will be a rational nearby, it won't necessarily be 'close enough' so that our irrational is contained in its given open ball.

Comment: But , how do we prove this ? I mean even if the size reduces exponentially , an irrational can always be found is what I understand .

Comment: A simple way to prove this is exactly what you said - the irrationals are a measurable set of measure $1$ (as the complement of a measure $0$ set), and so if you assume by contradiction that such a cover exists, then you get that their outer measure is smaller than $1$, which is a contradiction. Since you already showed explicitly that the rationals are measure $0$ - you can use it!

Comment: I think , the irrationals are a set of mesure 1 depends on what we are trying to prove .Isn't it so ?

Comment: No - once you've proven that the rationals are measurable of measure $0$, you get this corollary for free (by the definition of a measure space).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about this ? I am sorry Ii could not see how to get the corollary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112373/discussion-between-gsofer-and-itp-dusra).